# How to set an empty array in a for loop in JavaScript in case the array to loop is undefined?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, undefined

I want to loop over an array called `children` which may or may not be defined.

Currently I'm doing this:

```
var i;
var foo = {/*"children": ["1","2","3","4"]*/};


for (i = 0; i < [foo.children || []][0]. length; i += 1) {
   console.log("hello")
}
```

This works correctly, because in case `children` is undefined,  `[foo.children || []][0]` ends up being `[[]]` whose first element is an empty array `[]`.

**Question**:
Is there any way to leave away the outer array?

I don't want to use an if-clause testing for children, just modify the array.

One way would be:

```
for (i = 0; i < foo.children.length || [].length; i += 1) {
   console.log("hello")
}
```

but I'm looking for other alternatives if exist.

Thanks

**EDIT**:
[Here](http://jsperf.com/test-for-children) is a jsperf on all variants. Interesting...

Comment: why don't you want to use an `if` clause?  That would be the normal way, unless you're trying to write deliberately obfuscated code.

Comment: why don't you just use 0 instead of [].length?

Comment: just wondering if I could get by without if-clause, because I'm using a lot of checks for `if(foo.children.length) {...}`

Comment: @frequent if you're having to test it that often you should consider whether the correct design is for `children` to default to an empty array instead of not existing at all.

Comment: However you decide to do it, you should assign it to a variable before the loop, so you don't have to redo it each time through the loop.

Comment: @Jokey: I like a lot.

Comment: @Barmar you're kinda right, but that's also micro-optimisation.

Comment: @Alnitak Well, it will also make the code easier to understand, which is more important. Although if he's deliberately trying to obfuscate, I guess that would be counterproductive.

Comment: @Barmar fair point - it can be overkill if the condition is a constant, but it would indeed be better to avoid the conditional expression inside the loop construct, and it's how I'd write it myself.

Comment: @Alnitak: so you would not use the || inside the for-loop but rather "wrap" in `if (foo.children)`?

Comment: You could use a `try/catch` block :P Seriously, javascript can't read your mind.

Comment: Or use functions, you can hide everything inside them, and they lead to the most terse way to write code : `each(foo.children, function () {...})`, deal with `undefined` internally.

Comment: @frequent no, I meant that I would refactor the `length` expression out of the `for` loop, into its own variable.  This avoids re-evaluating that expression for each iteration.

Comment: @Alnitak: what I did: [http://jsperf.com/test-for-children](http://jsperf.com/test-for-children)

Comment: @frequent right, so unsurprisingly the version where the length is tested outside of the loop came first

Comment: @Alnitak: and I can add my "hidden" if-else in the kids declaration, so I'm going with this version. Thanks... make it an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var len = foo.children ? foo.children.length : 0;
for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I'd say this is a "hidden" if-statement :-)

Comment: So is `||`. They're all just different types of conditional operators.

Comment: @frequent: Isn't hiding the if-statement just what you're trying to do?

Comment: @Barmar in compiled languages a logical expression can produce code that doesn't branch, which can be much more efficient.

Comment: What are you really trying to accomplish? You don't seem to be looking for the most terse code, since you wrote `i += 1` rather than `i++`. So what is the real criteria for a good answer here?

Comment: @Barmar: most terse & JSlint (which does ask for += vs ++)

Comment: Are you really going to let Crockford dictate your programming style? That seems to be a personal bugaboo of his.

Comment: @Barmar: my boss let Crockford dictate my programming style :-)

Comment: @frequent Most of Crockford's _coding_ guidelines are fine.  His _style_ guidelines are IMHO, mostly a crock...

Answer (score 2):

Use parenthesis instead of that one-item-array:

```
for (i = 0; i < (foo.children || []).length; i += 1) {
```

or move it further outside:

```
for (i = 0; foo.children && i < foo.children.length; i += 1) {
```

which is very near to

```
if (foo.children) for (i = 0; i < foo.children.length; i += 1) {
```

which would indeed be the cleanest way. There's nothing wrong with an if-statement.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: According to comments on other answers the OP wants terse, but jsLint appropriate code. Here it is:

```
var i, c, foo = {}, console; 

for (i = 0, c = foo.children; i < (c && c.length); i += 1) {
    console.log("hello");
}
```

I will leave the other possibilitis here for people who don't have as strict requirements as the OP does.

---

You can use the `&&` operator:

```
for (i = 0; i < (foo && foo.children && foo.children.length); i += 1) {
   console.log("hello")
}
```

If there is a chance that `foo` is not defined at all, then you need something slightly worse:

```
for (i = 0; i < ((typeof foo === 'object') && foo.children && foo.children.length); i += 1) {
   console.log("hello")
}
```

Or if you're sure that `foo` is an object, you can skip the first check:

```
for (i = 0; i < (foo.children && foo.children.length); i += 1) {
   console.log("hello")
}
```

Comment: @frequent I'm afraid i don't understand. Perhaps you could explain so i can improve the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Another possible way:

```
for (i = 0; foo.children && i < foo.children.length; i += 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a condition checking the existence of the array to your for loop like this:

```
for (i = 0; (typeof foo.children != 'undefined') && (i < foo.children.length); i++) {
  // do something
}
```

/edit:
OK, others were a bit faster than me, and `foo.children` is a nice alternative to `typeof foo.children != 'undefined'` ;)

Comment: same here. valid, but I don't want to test for object existence.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using a function to hide all these dirty statements?

```
function each(array, fn) {
    if (array) {
        var i = -1;
        while (++i < array.length) {
            if (fn(array[i]) === false) return;
        }
    }
}
```